# Unexpected EOF error with pymssql

Tags: python, freetds, pymssql

We’ve been using pymssql and FreeTDS for over 2 years now without problems.  We recently upgraded pymssql to 2.1.3 and also from Python 3.4 to 3.6.  Since that upgrade we’ve been getting the following error intermittently (but frequently).

`(20017, b'DB-Lib error message 20017, severity 9:\nUnexpected EOF from the server (FBOps-Prod:1433)\nDB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (FBOps-Prod:1433)\n')`

There is no apparent pattern to the failures.  Well over 99% of the DB calls succeed and it can fail on any stored proc or sql.

I’ve scoured the web and come up empty.

I’ve reinstalled pymssql and FreeTDS but it still fails.

I’ve checked max number of connections and it’s 4096 which should be plenty as there are no more than 10 active users at a time.

I've verified that we close all DB connections properly.

I believe this is a FreeTDS error and posted to the FreeTDS mailing list but haven't received any response yet

Below is an excerpt from the TDS log file (full log file at the end).

```
    packet.c:639:Received packet
0000 04 01 00 11 00 5c 01 00-fd 00 00 d4 00 00 00 00 |.....\.. ........|
0010 00                     -                        |.|

token.c:565:processing result tokens.  marker is  fd(DONE)
token.c:2081:tds_process_end: more_results = 0
      was_cancelled = 0
      error = 0
      done_count_valid = 0
token.c:2098:                rows_affected = 0
token.c:2101:tds_process_end() state set to TDS_IDLE
util.c:165:Changed query state from READING to IDLE
util.c:83:logic error: cannot change query state from IDLE to PENDING
```

I’ve looked at the FreeTDS code but don’t have sufficient knowledge to understand why it’s failing.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever solve this in the end?